# CodeIgniter session holds value 1 instead of true

Tags: php, session, session-variables

In my codeigniter  application I have specified a session as below

```
$this->session->isLoggedIn = true;

echo "Session";

echo $this->session->isLoggedIn;
```

even though I assign true the output shows as 1 instead. What have I done wrong here?

would really appreciate some help

EDIT :- The problem was actually in the following

When I try to acess this session from another method the session value is set to null. My other function is defined as

```
public function isLoggedIn()
{
    var_dump($this->session->isLoggedIn);

    if ((isset($this->session->isLoggedIn)=="true"))
    {
        return "true";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Sorry,false";
    }
}
```

the vardump that I am printing in this isLoggedIn function is Null even though the session variable was assigned as displayed in the initial code above

Comment: What version of codeigniter?

Comment: PHP returns 0 as false and 1 as true.

Comment: Make `var_dump` instead of `echo` to see real value.

Comment: using codeigniter 3

Comment: var_dump actually shows as bool(true)

Comment: Pass your value in string 'true', you will get the result, you pass true as bool that always return 1 or if false then 0

Comment: @dev_tech then everything is fine. Echo converts `true` to 1.

Comment: alright thank you all for the advice! will try that.

Comment: @freeek The problem was actually somewhere else that I have no clue about seems like the session variable is not getting properly assigned I have updated the question above. Thanks for your time :)